# How to take (use, reuse) any data, returned by Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Suppose I wish to use Boltzmann constant in calculations, and I queried it from Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

Now, how to take any of selected values?

If I copy paste

[image]

I get garbage. How to perform?

Comment: Click the little (+) sign, choose "Subpod Content".

Comment: Hover the mouse over the value of choice, the little window drops down, click on the orange A in that which has alt text saying "copyable plain text", click on that and scrape and paste elsewhere

Comment: `{WolframAlpha["boltzmann constant", {{"Value", 1}, "NumberData"}], 
 WolframAlpha["boltzmann constant", {{"Value", 2}, "NumberData"}], 
 WolframAlpha["boltzmann constant", {{"Value", 3}, "NumberData"}], 
 WolframAlpha["boltzmann constant", {{"Value", 4}, "NumberData"}]}` Choose the appropriate units

Comment: Table[WolframAlpha["Boltzmann constant", {{"Value", n}, "ComputableData"}], {n, 4}]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to Wolfram Alpha, not Mathematica.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - the OP is calling W|A from within Mma and the question relates to how to use the results returned within Mma. I believe that this is a valid Mma question.

Comment: @BobHanlon  You are correct.  I should have considered the question more carefully.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the free-form input interface rather than the Wolfram | Alpha interface for this kind of thing.

[image: boltzmann]

```
UnitConvert[%]
```

> ```
> Quantity[1.38065*10^-23, ("Kilograms" ("Meters")^2)/("Kelvins" ("Seconds")^2)]
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to extract value namely from WA answer?